# Download image with text wordpress plugins

Tags: wordpress, image, text, plugins

I need wordpress plugins which allow me to download image with text on it. I exactly want images in slider and different text on every images. When I download image it comes with text written in image along with formatting such as bold, italic, font size, shadow etc...

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-force-images-download/ check this and also check https://wordpress.org/plugins/image-text-widget/

Comment: I'm struggling to understand your explanation of what you're looking for - maybe post an example image? Or some concrete example of what you're trying to achieve?